# Directive to disable elements and remove other [disabled] props

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm facing an interesting issue. We should implement a directive which disables UI elements depending on the user's role. For UI elements, which are not disabled by any other conditions it works but some buttons are disabled when at least one of many conditions is met and those conditions change when user interacts with the page.

```
// Directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[roleDisable]',
})
export class RoleDisableDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('roleDisable') role: string;
  @HostBinding('disabled') disabled: string;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>, 
    private elementRef: ElementRef, 
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkRights();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.checkRights();
  }

  private checkRights(): void {
    this.store.select(fromClient.hasNeededRole, {role: this.role }) //Observable<string>
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(hasRole => {
        // Attempt to remove [disabled], does not work
        if (element.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
          this.renderer.removeAttribute(element, 'disabled');
        }
        this.disabled = hasRole; // this works
     });
  }
}

// Usage in component template
<button
  roleDisable="start_process"
  mat-raised-button
  (click)="startProcess()"
  [disabled]="
    !processEnabled ||
    isUnavailable ||
    hasInputs ||
    preparationRunning ||
  "
>
```

If I remove the `[disabled]` prop with all the conditions the button gets disabled so the directive is working. But when the `[disabled]` calculation is kept and no condition is evaluated as `true` it will override the directive and the button gets enabled, which is unwanted behavior.

How can I force the directive to override/get rid of `[disabled]` prop calculation? Attempt to delete `[disabled]` prior to then disabling it again had no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Inject MatButton class in RoleDisableDirective directive to get mat-raised-btn instance then you can override MatButton disabled property in directive something like this.

**directive.ts**

```
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';

@Directive({
  selector: '[roleDisable]',
})
export class RoleDisableDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('roleDisable') role: string;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>,
    private matBtn:MatButton
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkRights();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.checkRights();
  }

  private checkRights(): void {
    this.store.select(fromClient.hasNeededRole, {role: this.role }) //Observable<string>
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(hasRole => {
        this.matBtn.disabled = true;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Button is enabled at first which it shouldn't be. Only get disabled with user interaction.

Comment: You can set disabled false on button element

Comment: This makes no difference whatsoever and the behavior seems to be unpredictable

Comment: Since you using  mat-raised-button on button element, button element will be projected inside mat-raised-button component that's why hostbinding is not working

Comment: I'm confused, @HostBinding is working. When I remove the `[disabled]` calculation from button it is disabled when I use the directive. Problem is that when I keep the calculation the directive will get overridden and button gets enabled

Comment: Issue is hostbinding is not working when you place disabled property on button element right?

Comment: It seems to be working I get no errors. As I've mentioned it looks like it is not treated as a definite state and it can be changed by other conditions. So hard to say whether it's not working at all or working but incorrectly.

Comment: Okay why can't you define one more input property in directive and pass down these expression result  (!processEnabled || isUnavailable || hasInputs || preparationRunning), and set disabled inside directive